# Option for PCs with low disk space?

Tags: eeepc, support, ubuntu-minimal

I am planning on running stock Ubuntu 12.04 on most of my PC's in order to get the five year LTS release support (and perhaps I will update one every six months out of curiousity).

I have an eeePC 701, which only has 4 GB of hard drive space, so running stock Ubuntu won't fit.  I presently have Peppermint One on it.  I've looked into Lubuntu (which is great), but is not getting five year support with 12.04.

I've looked at the Ubuntu mini.iso option and building it up from there, but am wondering if this route will get the five years of updates.

Anyone have any ideas/advice on upgrading a low spec machine to get the five year support?

Comment: Is installing Ubuntu on a USB stick an option?

Answer (score 3):

All Ubuntu derivatives that draw from the Ubuntu `main` repository will receive five years of updates for those packages. Since 'mini.iso' uses that repository, you should be fine.

It's worth noting that [Xubuntu 12.04](http://www.xubuntu.org/) will be getting special Canonical tender-love-n'-care as official derivative LTS. If you install via its Alternative Install CD, the final install size will be around two gigabytes, and will provide you a much richer, fully graphical environment.

Comment: Sounds great, will research more on Xununtu.

Afterwards will report here using a 701 and a 700 Surf (2 GB HDD)

Comment: Had problems when installing Xubuntu 12.04 ALT from a USB stick, so I am going to use a UBUNTU Builder program to build up a LXDE environemnt to use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install from the alternate install iso, and you will be able to install..

- Download the alternate install iso.
- Create a bootable usb key with this iso.
- Boot into the usb key and start the install.
- Install on your 4 gb SSD or alternatively unto a bigger removable SD card.
- You should NOT install on the usb key so be careful when choosing where to install.

as a side note.. some users have reported being able to create a softraid array using the internal 4gb SSD drive and an external 4gb SD card (creating thus a 8gb RAID-0 array) 
this could be worth a try if you can live with this constraint.. 
others also use a bigger (8GB,16GB,32GB) SD or SDHC card as their root drive and home directory and use their internal drive for extra storage etc etc.. 
this could be another option for you..

Good luck with your install.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running peppermint 3 on my Eeepc 4g for some years without an issue and still receiving updates. The latest is peppermint 6 [peppermint download page here](https://peppermintos.com/guide/downloading/) is based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS so that should tick your boxes. If space is a consideration remember to [clean out the old kernel images.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels) I tend to do this manually in synaptic searching for linux-images and deleting the older (lower numbered ones)